# in Gmail COMPOSE EMAIL, how can I alphabetize a list as part of an email?

Tags: gmail, formatting

In MS Word and MS Outlook, I can alphabetize a list inside an email (using the AtoZ macro) - but I can't find how to achieve this in Gmail web browser client.

Is it possible to do such advance edits in Gmail?

Comment: What app are you using for your gmail account ?

Comment: No such functionality is currently available as of now in the web interface, if you want to do such advance editing, you could set up your desktop email client for that.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to do that in Gmail. You'll need to use some other tool.